# Не запускается приложение на API 18

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать приложение с поддержкой тем для минимальных версий API.
Сейчас минимальная версия API 18, но в будущем я хочу еще снизить.

Проблема в том, что на API 18 приложение не запускается, а сразу падает с ошибкой. На API 21 работает.

Сначала я подумал, что это из-за того, что я ссылался на цвета через attrs, поэтому я внедрил цвет напрямую в XML Layout.

Но приложение как падало, так и падает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.app.peshkariki/com.app.peshkariki.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app.peshkariki.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.peshkariki-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.app.peshkariki-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.app.peshkariki.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app.peshkariki-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.app.peshkariki-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `multiDex` используется? Если да - прочтите документацию внимательно до конца: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-pre-l и убедитесь, что всё настроено правильно.